# getDownloadedDriverVersion() and getDownloadedDriverPath() is returning null for firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdrivermanager-java

Even after using latest WDM version, i am getting null for the below code

OS: Windows 11, Browser: firefox.

WDM version used.
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '5.4.1'

```
public static FirefoxDriver createDriver() {
        
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        
        System.out.println("DownloadedDriverPath >>> "
                + WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().getDownloadedDriverPath());

        System.out.println("DownloadedDriverVersion >>> "
            + WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().getDownloadedDriverVersion());

        System.out.println("BrowserPath >>> "
                + WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().getBrowserPath());
        
        
        return driver;
    }
```

Please help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
WebDriverManager wmd = WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver();
wdm.setup();
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.out.println("DownloadedDriverPath >>> " + wdm.getDownloadedDriverPath());
```